# How would i go about implementing ' '.format() into this code?

Tags: python

I've been trying to make a program that approximates a number through dichotomy by using a given precision (numbers after decimal) however after 12+ numbers after decimal the number gets put in scientific form (for example 6.103515625e-05). I've been trying to use ''.format() to fix this issue but i can't seem to understand where it should go in the code:

```
    def solveByDichotomy(i, j, k):
    r = 0
    while(len(str(i-int(i))) < j):
        i = i/2
        r += 1
        if k == True :
            print(i)
    print("Le résultat final est " + str(i))
    print("La résolution fut composée de " + str(r) + " étapes.")
```

is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

The `:f` formatting directive specifies that the number should be printed as floating point:

```
>>> n = 5 / 1000000
>>> n
5e-06
>>> f"{n}"
'5e-06'
>>> f"{n:f}"
'0.000005'
```

so in the last two lines of your function, do:

```
    print(f"Le résultat final est {i:f}")
    print(f"La résolution fut composée de {r} étapes.")
```

(You can do the same thing with `.format()` as well, but f-strings are easier to read and are considered the "correct" way to format strings in most situations now.)